# What is the tax savings for charitable giving when you have both ordinary income and capital gains?

Tags: united-states, taxes, charitable-contributions

Say, for example, I make $300,000 in ordinary income this year and $300,000 in capital gains.

If I donate $10,000 from my cash accounts to charity, does the deduction get applied to my ordinary income tax rate or my capital gains income tax rate first?

Comment: Did you donate $10k in cash or appreciated stock?

Comment: Sneaky question, Joe. I thought this was a no-brainer to answer, now I see where this is going.

Comment: I donated cash (hypothetically!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Charitable deductions (and all Schedule A deductions) are applied to your marginal tax calculation. They reduce the taxable income on the line 43 of your tax return (form 1040). When you calculate your tax on the [capital gains tax worksheet](https://apps.irs.gov/app/vita/content/globalmedia/capital_gain_tax_worksheet_1040i.pdf), you start with that number. You then deduct all the capital gains from it and calculate the ordinary tax on line 24 of the worksheet.